# Compare large excel sheets

Tags: excel, comparison, large-data

I have two excel files with one column but a large number of different cells in each file - between 5,000-10,000. I want to run a comparison between the two files to show me duplicates, and I can't seem to find how to do that efficiantly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `XMATCH()` function. If you got any number value then it exist to second list. If you got error then no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, but that only covers the exact match. I’m playing around with it and trying to locate the similar items but the options for bigger/smaller I get from excel are not really similar. Any ideas?